# MapServer WFS request

Tags: openlayers, wfs, mapserver

I want to request a WFS feature but my mapfile returns WMS, I have tried to change the mapfile but it still returns the WMS. I am using MapServer 7.3 and OpenLayers 4. Below is my mapfile

```
...                     
WEB
    TEMPLATE "/data/mapFile/template.html"
    IMAGEPATH "/data/mapFile/output/"
    IMAGEURL "/data/mapFile/output/"

    METADATA
        'wfs_title'             'Provincial Boundaries'
        'wfs_onlineresource'    'http://*****/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/data/mapFile/South.map'
        'wfs_srs'               'EPSG:4326'
        "wfs_abstract"          "Provincial boundaries" 
        'wfs_enable_request'    '*' 
    END
END

PROJECTION
    'init=epsg:4326'
END

LAYER
    NAME    'south'
    METADATA
        "wfs_title"             "Provincial Boundaries"
        "wfs_srs"               "EPSG:4326"
        "gml_include_items"     "all"
        "wfs_request_method"    "GET"
        "gml_featureid"         "ID"
        "wfs_enable_request"    "*"
    END
    CONNECTIONTYPE WFS
    TYPE    POLYGON
    STATUS  ON
    DATA    '/Data/Webmapping/National/Provinces.shp'
    TRANSPARENCY 100
    PROJECTION
        'init=epsg:4326'
    END
    CLASS
        NAME    'Privincial Boundaries' 
        STYLE
            WIDTH 0.55 
            OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
        END
    END
END
....
```

And below is my layer

```
africa = new ol.layer.Tile({ 
  visible : true,
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: 'http://*****/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/data/mapFile/South.map',     
      params: {
          'LAYERS': 'south', 
          'TRANSPARENT': true
      }
  })
});
```

Comment: You ask for TileWMS from the client side. Ask for WFS.

Comment: You can check that a WFS is enabled by making a GetCapabilities request

Comment: e.g using `http://*****/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/data/mapFile/South.map&service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&`

Answer (score 2):

The map file is correct. In OpenLayers, you have created a tile layer and its source is tileWMS, that's why you are getting WMS. to get WFS,

```
africa_wfs_source = new ol.source.vector({
    format : new ol.format.GeoJson(),
    url: function(extent) {
        return 'http://*****/cgi-bin/mapserv? 
        map=/data/mapFile/South.map&service=WFS&' +
        'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=south&' +
        'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
        'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
    },
    strategy: bboxStrategy
});


var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: africa_wfs_source,
    style: new ol.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
            width: 2
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments the reason why you are getting a WMS response from MapServer in OpenLayers is because you are asking for a WMS response!

e.g.

...source: new ol.source.**TileWMS**({...